# Is in aws SMS service Server Migration Connector requires a service account in Active Directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am planning migrate Hyper-V(all vm's from hyper-v/ESXi) to aws using AWS SMS (server migration service ). 
my hyper-v is testing environment and which is out of Active directory.

As per document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/latest/userguide/HyperV.html Step 1 showing to **Create a Service Account for Server Migration Connector in Active Directory**

My query is , is this step is mandatory to migrate hyper-v to AWS?. because i don't have Active directory.